# excel vba sumif 2 conditions in 2 worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I have two worksheets in Excel and I'm trying to control 2 conditions (in two different Ranges, in the same worksheet) in the second worksheet, but the vba Code is for the first worksheet. How can I realise that with the "SumIf"-Function

the Problem is the following:

```
SumIf(worksheet1.Range("A:A"),condition1,worksheet1.Range("N:N"))

SumIf(worksheet1.Range("H:H"),condition2,worksheet1.Range("N:N"))
```

**The sum "Range("N:N")" needs to be done only once under conditons1 and condition2**

**How can I make it with only one "SumIf" ?**

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `SumIfs()`:

```
SumIfs(worksheet1.Range("N:N"),worksheet1.Range("A:A"),condition1,worksheet1.Range("H:H"),condition2)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can I add more than as 2 condtions with  SumIfs ?

Comment: You can use up to 14 range-condition pairs.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped you, please accept and upvote! Thank you.